# How to get browser name using Selenium WebDriver with Java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a test case and need to execute based on the browser name i.e. IE or Chrome. In this test case some part will depend on browser type.

How will I get the browser name in between the execution? Example if it is IE, I need to pass the data. If it is Chrome browser, I need to select the data.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use below code to know browser name, version and OS details:-

```
    Capabilities cap = ((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getCapabilities();
    String browserName = cap.getBrowserName().toLowerCase();
    System.out.println(browserName);
    String os = cap.getPlatform().toString();
    System.out.println(os);
    String v = cap.getVersion().toString();
    System.out.println(v);
```

packages you need to import

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
```

OR

```
   Capabilities cap = ((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getCapabilities();

    String browserName = cap.getBrowserName();
    String browserVersion = (String)cap.getCapability("browserVersion");
    String osName = Platform.fromString((String)cap.getCapability("platformName")).name().toLowerCase();

    return browserName + browserVersion + "-" + osName;
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: If the OP had (one or more) `driver` instances, why would they need code to work out the name so that *only then* could they switch on it? Where is the instance going to come from in the first place?

Comment: OP can use this code on the testcases where he need to know the version and browser. OP can change the driver instance name. I just answered whatever OP has asked for.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me - but it's OP's choice.

Comment: How can i get the browser details using EventFiringWebDriver (c#) ? I'm getting "Invalid cast" exception while trying to cast EventFiringWebDriver to RemoteWebDriver

Answer (score 8):

In Python, you may access the `driver.capabilities` dict like this

```
driver.capabilities['browserName']
```

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-users/nbSujBSc6q8

Comment: You've written the wrong name for the dict: it's called `driver.capabilities["name_of_attribute"]` If you plural it it works great.

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve the *Browser Name* , *Browser Version*  and *Platform Name*  you can use either of the following approaches:

- Using the API directly:

  - Code Block:

    ```
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

    public class browserCapabilitiesRetrieve {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            // initial configuration
            System.out.println("Browser Name is : "+((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getCapabilities().getBrowserName().toLowerCase());
            System.out.println("Browser Version is : "+((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getCapabilities().getVersion().toString());
            System.out.println("Platform Name is : "+((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getCapabilities().getPlatform().toString());
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
    ```
- Using the *Capabilities* object and `getCapability()` method:

  - Code Block:

    ```
    import org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

    public class FirefoxBrowserCapabilitiesRetrieve_getCapability {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            // initial configuration
            Capabilities cap = ((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getCapabilities();
            System.out.println("Browser Name is : "+cap.getBrowserName());
            System.out.println("Browser version is : "+cap.getVersion());           
            System.out.println("Platform is : "+cap.getPlatform().toString());
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
    ```

Answer (score 1):

For those using C# you can do the following to detect browser when using either the local browser driver or remotewebdriver:

```
        public static bool IsSafari(IWebDriver driver)
        {
            // Using remotewebdriver e.g. browserstack
            if (SomeConfig.UsingRemoteWebDriver)
                return GetRemoteDriverBrowserName(driver) == "safari";
            // Using local browser driver
            return driver.GetType() == typeof(SafariDriver);
        }

        public static bool IsInternetExplorer(IWebDriver driver)
        {
            // Using remotewebdriver e.g. browserstack
            if (SomeConfig.UsingRemoteWebDriver)
                return GetRemoteDriverBrowserName(driver) == "internet explorer";
            // Using local browser driver
            return driver.GetType() == typeof(InternetExplorerDriver);
        }

        private static string GetRemoteDriverBrowserName(IWebDriver driver)
        {
            return ((RemoteWebDriver)driver).Capabilities.GetCapability("browserName").ToString().ToLower();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're the tester, so it's up to you to write code/scripts to **explicitly** test each of the various browser/version combinations and their various nuances and subtleties (whilst trying to reuse as much logic as you can, minimise duplication etc.)

The nature of WebDriver is that **you**, the tester, are doing the driving - not the browser. Don't try to detect things.

So given that you have different behaviour for IE and for Chrome, you should explicitly create a `WebDriver` instance for each (in different `@Test`s) and set up the required data (likewise properties, `Capabilities` etc.) as appropriate.

By all means share common lookup code between the tests, but until your tests are robust and working you shouldn't try to refactor them.

Comment: While you have a point, IMHO there are cases where it is better if the tests automatically adapt to different browsers. For example: tests are often run (semi)manually against different browsers; or one browser requires a work around for a Selenium bug when interacting with certain elements. For these cases you don't want separate tests, you want one test that works across browsers.

Comment: Different browsers require slight adjustments to code, and detecting which browser is being used enables your code to be more intelligent.  For instance currently Safari requires most clicks to be executed via javascript, so detecting whether it's safari and altering how a click is performed via a selenium extension is the sensible approach.  Some browsers deal with window switching slightly differently as well as of today's date, logic based on browser type is then also required.

Answer (score 0):

To list all capabilities in Java you can use:

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

for (String s : ((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getCapabilities().getCapabilityNames()) {
    System.out.println(s + " :: " + ((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getCapabilities().getCapability(s));
}
```