# unable to locate element error in python when element is clearly present

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import httpagentparser
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/")
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("user agent online")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
ua=driver.find_element_by_class_name("_Mqr")
uaa=httpagentparser.simple_detect(ua)
driver.close()
```

i even tried implicit_wait() but it does not work and still returns element not found exception.please help me with this problem.

Comment: So where are you having a problem?

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, ["it doesn't work"](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: when i am using implicit or explicit wait,i am getting a timeout exception

Comment: which element not found? is the `q` or `Mqr` or both?

Answer (score 0):

try explicit wait

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/")
try:
    elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "q"))
    )
    elem.clear()
    elem.send_keys("user agent online")
    elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    # your code
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: I tried this code byt it gives me a timeout exception

Comment: Time exception is gone but im still getting the NoSuchElementException

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the modifications to your own script as :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/")
try:
    elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "q")))
    elem.clear()
    elem.send_keys("user agent online")
    print("Found 1st Element")
    elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "_Mqr")))
    print("Found 2nd Element")
finally:
    print("Finishing Up Now")
driver.close()
```

Only added explicit wait condition to both elements.

Also got the following output which shows the script is working as expected :

```
Found 1st Element
Found 2nd Element
Finishing Up Now
```

Comment: i want to write a code such that it has to give the end users browser information ,but using selenium we have to specify whether to use chrome or firefox driver.how can do it?

Comment: Use following link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35258079/how-to-get-browser-name-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java

Comment: I want to find out his default browser and give driver instance only for that browser